# Force download when serving static files with apache tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I know I can serve static files in apache tomcat by defining a new context:

```
<Context docBase="/home/stuff" path="/static" />
```

Is there a configuration to make tomcat force the downloading of the files being served (by setting response headers) instead of showing these files in the browser?

Comment: Whether to show the content inline ("in browser") or to show the Save dialog is completely browser's responsibility. You can try to use the [download](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute when linking, or you can try to set `Content-Disposition: Attachment` and e.g. `Content-type: application/octet-stream`, but it's browser's responsibility, what it will do.

Comment: Anyway, it'd be useful to look into `mime-mapping` elements in `conf/web.xml` file of your Tomcat instance.